# Coordinate Conversion in PostGIS

Tags: postgis-2.0, geotools

I have some problem with the representation of the coordinates.
I need to convert the coordinates from "EPSG: 32633" to "EPSG: 4326", and then create geometries in PostGIS.
For the conversion (from java) I use GeoTools.

```
double xc = 586073.93799999997;
double yc = 4644834.9100000001;
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(xc, yc);
Point p = gf.createPoint(c);
CoordinateReferenceSystem utmCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:32633");
CoordinateReferenceSystem tCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
MathTransform mathTransform = CRS.findMathTransform(utmCrs, tCrs, false);
Point p1 = (Point) JTS.transform(p, mathTransform);
System.out.println(p1.getCoordinate());
```

with the output:

> (40.271915834122524, 17.83405351767443, NaN)

However, this representation is wrong for PostGIS.

```
create table coordinate(
id int  primary key,
tipo varchar(15)
);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('coordinate','luogo','4326','POINT',2);
INSERT INTO coordinate(id, tipo, luogo) VALUES(1,'calcare', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40.271915834122524, 17.83405351767443)', 4326));
```

returns

> ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry HINT: 
>   "POINT(40.271915834122524, " <-- parse error at position 26 within
>   geometr

how can I solve my problem?

...
the wkt of GeoTools is the same as that contained in spatial_ref_sys:

```
crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
wkt = crs.toWKT();
System.out.println("\n\nwkt for EPSG:4326");

wkt for EPSG:4326
GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) (i.e., no comma). To easily get this out, use [`toText()`](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#toText%28%29):

```
System.out.println(p1.toText());
```

or directly specify X and Y values, which is useful if you want to eventually parameterise the inserts:

```
INSERT INTO coordinate(id, tipo, luogo)
VALUES(1,'calcare', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(40.271915834122524, 17.83405351767443), 4326));
```